# Как заставить Mozilla понимать @font-face?

Tags: css3, шрифты, css

Добрый вечер.

При попытке подключить нестандартный шрифт в проект через `@font-face` `Mozilla` отказывается его отображать. Не подскажите как победить подобное поведение?

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Haettenschweiler';
    src: url('pathToFont/haettenschweiler-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../font/haettenschweiler-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Поместил `TrueType` выше - также результатов не принесло.

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/css/font-face гласит ,что должно поддерживатся

Comment: А всё-таки код в студию. И шрифт.

Comment: для меня тоже подобная ситуация нелепой кажется) Ожидал больше проблем от `IE7`. Ан-нет!

Comment: @klopp, а шрифт-то как я сюда залью?))

Comment: Ссылку дать. BTW, ttf понимается, [например](http://sova.msk.ru/): (болванка, но в исходник глянуть можно, и шрифт скачать для пробы)

Comment: `TrueType` есть в перечне.

Comment: Я не слепой, в примере из поста никакого ttf нет.

Comment: Есть в посте, есть в коде - не особо что-то помогает.

Comment: Теперь появился :) Варианты: 1) поднять ttf наверх 2) вообще убрать wuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько мне известно немного криво прописан путь либо же не до конца сконвертирован сам шрифт. Я конвертирую на сайте [@font-face Generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) и конечный результат должен быть таким:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'robotoitalic';
    src: url('../fonts/roboto-italic-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/roboto-italic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/roboto-italic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/roboto-italic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/roboto-italic-webfont.svg#robotoitalic') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
```

Также важен путь ../fonts/ у меня он расположен в корневой папке в папке fonts.

А у вас два разных пути прописаны pathToFont/ и ../font/ как это понимать?

Comment: это уже было исправление, поэтому и разные пути. я тоже генерировал шрифт именно на этом сайте. спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Вероятней всего, проблемы не с тегом, а с форматом woff, надо делать "костыль" для него )))

Comment: [про WOFF читал тут](http://www.xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/typographics/font-face-in-the-details.html)